# django custom form template checkbox question

Tags: django, django-forms

Django forms are really easy and nice to style especially if you like to take control of the outcome.

A question. Is there anyway you can see whether the `{{ field }}` type, ie checkbox, radio etc?

Comment: It seems not (at least is not something in the field or in the widget classes). Can I ask you why you need this ?

Comment: @Tommaso, I just want to take style the way the the checkboxes look ie put them into columns etc, although there aren't that many, so I might just exclude it, from the {% for %} and hardcode them.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a field_type template filter

```
{{ field|field_type }} = CharField 
{{ field|widget_type }} = TextInput
```

heres a great example :

http://olivergeorge.posterous.com/django-template-tags-to-find-out-field-type